# How can I check if a value is of type Map in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a variable that could be an Object, a Map, or neither. I can easily check for objects with `typeof`, but I need to conditionally `Map.map()` the variable if it is a Map, and `typeof` doesn't work with maps. Any suggestions?

Comment: `instanceof` is what you're looking for

Comment: @Pointy could I get some context with that?

Comment: @DeathWaltz — It’s a JS operator. It’s well documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use instanceof:

```js
var map = new Map;
console.log(map instanceof Map);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var foo = new Set;
foo instanceof Set; // True!
foo instanceof Map; // False!
```